Why does electric current not disobey Heisenberg's uncertainty principle?
So, the definition of current, or the magnitude of current, that I have found is that it's the rate at which the electrons flow through a cross-section of a wire. But that means knowing exactly where the electrons are which means their momentum has very high uncertainty, which I don't think is the case. And also I have recently learnt that electrons actually move really slowly in a wire, at like 0.1 mm/s, and it's actually the EMF that carries the energy. I guess so my actual question is what is the formal definition of current.

Fermi electron velocity is indeed many km/s. The mean electron flow speed calculated from the macroscopic current is an average quantity. Electrons aren't slowly creeping through the metallic wire.

I gather that, since you aren't using terminology from statistical mechanics, you aren't well versed in that subject?  Suffice it to say, precise answers can be found there: it is in that domain where the individual states of atoms and orbitals, and electron wave functions, are joined together and summed over, to give the behavior of condensed-matter physics as we know it.  This includes bulk properties like heat capacity and density, but also electronic properties like electron flow, spin effects like magnetism, energy band structures, semiconductor physics and more.
Lacking that (and frankly, fortunately, as it's been a long time since I worked any problems in stat mech myself, but also that it's a notoriously difficult subject in general..!), a hand-waving explanation ought to suffice.
Consider the cross-section of a metal wire.  A given conduction electron in that wire, at room temperature, might have an equivalent wavelength of, say, a few dozens of atomic spacing.  Roughly speaking, a couple electrons can fit into that state, plus complementary (spin paired) and nearby states.  Lower-energy states pack in tighter still, though they move slower (or can't at all), all the way down to bound (valence) states where electrons are localized to individual atomic orbitals (or pairs or whatever).
Needless to say, there's a [take your pick of expletives]-tonne of electrons available in a metal.  Like, in the 1027/cm3 range.  States are not in short supply, even if mostly just the highest-energy states have vacancies to move electrons between (and thus current flow).
The fact that the mean drift velocity, or the electric field, for practical current densities, is so low, means that we are very far indeed from exhausting the current conduction capacity of a metal.  This can be done in semiconductors, where give or take material properties, a constant-current or even negative-resistance characteristic is obtained (as charge carriers achieve saturation velocity or ballistic transport).
Quantum effects can indeed be observed in wires, but it requires extremely small wires for the energy levels to become evident: a few nm across, dozens of atoms, where conduction-band electrons become quantized (very roughly in a manner of speaking: they go "single file").
In short, there are just so many energy levels and free electrons available, that even in the poorest metals, conduction is free, practically unlimited -- at least for short time scales, until overheating or electromigration damage occurs.

Regarding EMF, be careful here: a lot of people play fast and loose with this fact.  The intent, is to get one to think in terms of, not the wire itself, but the space around the wire, and the boundary of that space; to think of the wire and its surroundings as a transmission line, or waveguide.  This does not apply at DC, and isn't significant for frequencies where skin effect is insignificant, where resistance dominates over inductance and capacitance.
Transmission lines are the more general definition (or fields further still), but we don't need to invoke them when doing simple problems, and we make a lot of busy-work for ourselves when we do (which is a good exercise once in a while, don't get me wrong -- but you're not supposed to work real problems that way all the time).
In particular, for DC current flow, the applied electric field, and the probability of scattering events (electron-phonon interactions, impurities, etc.; on average, an electron hits a "bump" about every 80 atoms or so in room-temperature copper, I think it was?) determines the current flow, i.e. the bulk resistivity of the material.  More scattering leads to a more frustrated trajectory, more exchange of velocity (accumulated by traversing the electric field) into heat (atomic vibrations, phonons), less current flow -- more resistance.
Conduction happens entirely due to the electric field within the material.  At radio frequencies, EM fields are excluded from the bulk (skin effect dominates), and largely propagate in the space between conductors instead; it's more correct to model such structures as transmission lines, waveguides.
Finally, take note of when and where those exceptions occur.  At the surface, within the skin effect, electric field is still dropped through the material, current flows, and resistance occurs.  The dominance of one regime or another, does not exclude the other -- do not accept such absolute descriptions!
There is no such thing as absolute in physics: everything is a bit of this and that, here or there, and the challenge is solving for the sum total effects down to some reasonable error margin.  We might not be concerned with the bulk resistivity of metal in a microwave resonator structure, but that's not to say it doesn't still play a role.
Intent is a tricky thing to convey; nuance, even more so.  One might use absolute phrasing to try and jog the mind out of a fixed way of thinking -- but one must use it carefully, because that absolutism simply implies another (perhaps alternative, perhaps superseding) absolute condition.  In other words, an outcome that is just as intellectually dishonest (or toxic, even) as the starting case!
So, just an FYI: in the sciences, when someone says "this always happens", "100%", "certainly", etc.... they probably only mean 99%, or within some error bars, or given certain assumptions defining the case (which they may not always remember to include with the problem setup, and which may make all the difference when applying the conclusion to another, seemingly similar case).  There are few things absolutely for certain, and it doesn't hurt to check -- "when you say 'always', do you reaaaally mean 'always always'?"  It's not that it never happens, there are many extraordinarily-well-proven laws that we can take as absolute -- but just be careful separating those from the more informal "it's mostly this" wording.
Put still another way: it's an unfortunate outcome of, somewhere between just the way linguistics works (a lot of people will take 95%+ as "always happens"..), or a result of compartmentalized thinking (putting some physical system, and its related effects, into one mental box, that it doesn't quite fit into, and needs to spill out into related boxes -- or better yet is treated with the continuous nuance that the real thing exhibits).

The Lumped Element Model (LEM) is used to describe algebraically the behaviour of electrical circuits. This model distills the unimaginable chaos and randomness of moving charges, down into a very simple set of algebraic relationships, in terms of current \$I\$, voltage \$V\$ and resistance/impedance \$R\$. The LEM is where we get Ohm's law:
$$ V = I \times R $$
Kirchhoff's current and voltage laws also come from the LEM, and its terms "current" and "voltage" are really just descriptions of the statistical mean state of huge numbers of charges. Even though we can never know the entire state of any individual charge, due to the uncertainty principle, we can predict with great accuracy and precision the average state and behaviour of huge numbers of them.
In the context of the LEM, electrical current is defined to be the amount of electric charge passing through some cross-section of a conductor, each second. In a medium where the mobile charge carriers are electrons (such as copper), current would be equal to the product of an individual electron's charge \$e^-=-1.6\times10^{-19}\rm{\ C}\$ and the number \$N\$ of charges passing through that cross section, per unit time \$t\$:
$$ I = \frac{e^-N}{t} $$
Quantum effects make it impossible to know the exact number \$N\$, but since we are usually dealing with millions to quintillions of charges, that number on average is remarkably consistent and predictable.
Voltage is a measure of the potential energy possessed by charges at one point in a circuit, relative to charges somewhere else. Like current, this is a statistical average, since at any instant in time, some charges will have more potential energy than others nearby, but the average electrical potential energy of huge numbers of charges near some specific point in a conductor is consistent and predictable.
Unlike current, potential energy only has meaning relative to the potential energy of charges somewhere else, since there's no "absolute zero joule" reference point anywhere. That's why voltage is always a "potential difference" between two points.
As charges travel from a place with some potential to another place with different potential, they lose potential energy, donating it to the environment as they travel. During that journey, the total amount of energy exchanged between charges and their environment each second (power \$P\$) will depend on both the amount of energy they each have to donate (potential difference \$V\$), and the number of charges that make that journey each second (current \$I\$):
$$ P = V \times I $$
So while it isn't wrong to say that the source of energy is an EMF (potential difference), the rate at which that energy is delivered, which we call power, is also a function of current.
TLDR:
The titular question is "why does electric current not disobey Heisenberg's uncertainty principle?". The answer is that it does obey. It's just that the uncertainty of the momentum and position of individual charges is insignificant compared to the consistency of average behaviour of huge numbers of charges, in the same way that thousands of vehicles are leaving and entering Paris at any given instant, seemingly at random, and yet the average total number of vehicles in Paris is constant.


What is the formal definition of current?

Electric current (I) is the rate at which electric charge (Q) flows through a conductor.  It is defined as: $$I=\dfrac{dQ}{dt}$$
Where \$I\$ is the current in amperes, \$dQ\$ is the charge in coulombs, and \$dt\$ is the time in seconds.

\$\text{Current  Velocity     }\$
When one coulomb of charge flows through a conductor in one second, the current is one ampere.
The direct flow of electrons is like the visual effect of handwaves around a football stadium.  (except the people rotate around the stadium say at 0.1mm/s).
The dielectric constant (Dk), also known as the relative permittivity (\$ϵ_r\$​), of the surrounding insulation, which is attracted to the conductors, stores the charge. Specifically, Dk of air is approximately 1.0006 at standard conditions (room temperature and atmospheric pressure). This means that air has almost the same ability to store electrical energy as a vacuum, and has a relative dielectric constant of exactly 1.0.
The conductors bump electrons in one end and out the other to create the current.  With resistance, R can dissipate power and eventually, the wave of direct current dies out. The resistance or conductors cannot store energy but depending on their length and shape can exhibit inductance, L that depends on the length/diameter ratio (\$ln(\frac{l}{d})\$) and will have some incremental inductance (\$L'\$ ~ 1 uH/m) which can store a small amount of energy proportional to the length of the closed loop path of current.
The speed of the electrons is much faster than the "hands".  In conductors and insulators, the speed of light in a vacuum is reduced by the relative dielectric constant, Dk surrounding the conductors. It is defined in a vacuum as 1.0, in the air is \$ϵ_r\$ = 1.0001 ( The other name for dielectric is insulator like air or water) If the hands were under water they would slow down a lot because in water \$ϵ_r=80\$. The speed of photons and electrons in a vacuum = c but slows down in a dielectric by \$V_f=\frac{c}{\sqrt{\epsilon _r}}\$.
For pure PTFE (Teflon)( \$v_f​=\frac{c}{\sqrt{2.1}} ​≈0.69c\$ ) or 69% of c but other plastic additives bring this up to 80% of c in commercial coax cable.
\$\text{Fun Fact}\$
The reason we get advance warning of a coronal mass ejection (CME) event heading towards Earth, travels slower than the RF data transmission from the satellites surrounding the Sun. This means the gigatonness of plasma particles and hot gasses have a dielectric constant \$ϵ_r\$ greater than 1 which is the vacuum between Sun and the Earth. The CME then pings towards the poles of the magnetosphere with steeks of ion collisions producing beautiful Aurora. But if large enough, pings the magnetosphere to wobble at some low frequency and can induce millions of volts on long grid wires and may cause Transformer damage. The last record of this happening was in 1859 known as the Carrington Event which struck Earth for 5 seconds and the arcing on Telegraph wires and gaslamps lasted till the next day.  More historic details of plasma current

The low drift velocity of electrons in a wire is a consequence of the enormous quantity of electrons in comparison to the charge flow involved in sensible currents. In fact it's more like a very slight bias (like 1 part in 10^9) in the thermal motion of the electrons at room temperature.

Yes the drift of electrons is average difference in random motion density  dQ/dt divided by wire cross-X area, A and by charge, e of an electron and by the number, n of free electrons per unit volume $v_d​=\frac{dQ}{dt⋅A⋅e⋅n}$​
